# Improve Loading speed of Excel into R dataframe

Tags: r, excel, time, dataframe, load

I am loading an excel spreadsheet in R using xlsx package. It has 50 + columns and 2000 + rows. Load time is around 12 minutes. Is there a way to improve the load speed?

Code I am using :

```
library(xlsx)
starttime = Sys.time()
res = read.xlsx("ExcelSheet.xlsx",sheetName = "Sheet1")
endtime = Sys.time()  - starttime

print (endtime)
```

Comment: Okay. How does readxl improve loading speed? Does it process excel data differently? Would like to understand the difference.

Comment: It may be easier just to save the Excel file as a .csv.

Comment: `readxl` should get the job done, but you could also try `xlsx::read.xlsx2`. `read.xlsx2` is much faster than `read.xlsx`.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning the Excel file into a `.csv` file instead. `.csv`s read much faster, everything should load in under a minute.

Comment: Data I am dealing with is formatted (i.e numeric columns, currencies etc). If I put it on csv, it loads faster but when I do a str(dataframe) it has processed the data all wrong. Is there a way to get over those formats?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @eipi , @jenesaisquoi, @alistaire. 
I could load the data much faster using read.xlsx2.